# Can I translate .net assembly versions to dates?

Tags: .net

All of my .NET assemblies uses the 1.0.* format for their version numbers. Supposedly the * gets replaced with the current date and time, translated into a number. What is the formula to translate it back into a date and time?

Comment: Ticks? `new DateTime(long ticks)`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean, please?

Comment: Where did you learn that the * gtes relaced with the current date/time?

Comment: I think that * gets replaced with the number of seconds since midnight or the number of days since 1st Jan 1970, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998223.aspx for more info.

Comment: Actually the date isn't fixed from the MSDN page:
"The result of this is a build number set to the number of days since a random, designated start date and the revision based on the number of seconds since midnight."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`AssemblyVersionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) documentation states that:

> The default build number increments daily. The default revision number
>   is the number of seconds since midnight local time (without taking
>   into account time zone adjustments for daylight saving time), divided
>   by 2.

The reference date for the build number isn't specified. In practice, I've found this to be 1 January 2000.

The date can therefore be reconstructed as follows:

```
var result = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
result = result.AddDays(buildNumber);
result = result.AddSeconds(revision * 2);
```

Since the reference date isn't documented, it can't be guaranteed to always remain unchanged.

Comment: It's odd that the documentation now says the date is random.  8 or so years ago, I have a vivid memory of reading that it was from 1/1/2000. -- Perhaps they changed that.

Answer (score 5):

In Roslyn and .NET Core, the compiler source code is now available.

The file `roslyn/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/VersionHelper.cs` ( https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/614299ff83da9959fa07131c6d0ffbc58873b6ae/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/VersionHelper.cs - from commit [4f44984 on 2016-04-19](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/4f4498439bc28d1a3be5a4759b7f5ed60ae142e8) ) does have the same date logic from the original `csc` in the method `GenerateVersionFromPatternAndCurrentTime`:

```
int revision = (int)time.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds / 2;

// 24 * 60 * 60 / 2 = 43200 < 65535
Debug.Assert(revision < ushort.MaxValue);

// ...

TimeSpan days = time.Date - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
int build = Math.Min(ushort.MaxValue, (int)days.TotalDays);

return new Version(pattern.Major, pattern.Minor, (ushort)build, (ushort)revision);
```

However the documentation comments simply say "a time-based value" without being specific about how it's generated.

But indeed, so far the `Build` is still days since 2000-01-01 and `Revision` is *half* the number of seconds since midnight.

Interestingly, this behavior *is defined and verified* in the test cases in `VersionHelperTests.cs`: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/614299ff83da9959fa07131c6d0ffbc58873b6ae/src/Compilers/Core/CodeAnalysisTest/VersionHelperTests.cs

Answer (score 2):

The version string has this format:

```
<major version>.<minor version>.<build number>.<revision>
```

and if you set the version as you've described, to `1.0.*`:

> The result of this is a build number
>   set to the number of days since a
>   random, designated start date and the
>   revision based on the number of
>   seconds since midnight.

The key here is "random".  So, you can translate the revision to a time of day, but it sounds like you won't be able to resolve it to a date.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998223.aspx

Comment: Interesting, your MSDN link and my link conflict with each other a bit.

Comment: Sorry, @Michael - I accidentally edited your post, then realize my mistake and deleted my edits from your post and put them in my own.  It was an accident.  *Sorry*

Comment: But +1 to you since it looks like your conclusion is how I read it as well.

Comment: @David: no problem.  I agree with your conclusion that it's poor practice to rely on that behavior.

Comment: Who says I'm relying on it? Perhaps I'm just looking for a little bit of extra info. Or maybe I'm building a new compiler and want the same behavior just in case someone else is relying on it.

Comment: @Grauenwolf: Um, nobody said you're relying on it.  Only that it's poor practice to do so.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx): "The default build number increments daily. The default revision number is random."

If you look at the source for `AssemblyVersionAttribute` in reflector, you will see it's not doing anything at all, just accepting the string. So the magic happens with the compiler itself, which as far as I can tell is not documented anywhere. "Incremented everyday" is pretty vague, starting from what point?

I wouldn't expect to be able to use these versions with any reliability. It is probably better to base your version off of a label in a source control system or something like that.

Comment: Reliability isn't important, I just need something.

Comment: Reliability is important though. This is a community driven site. It's important that others looking for the same information get accurate info. Quick hacks that are questionably sound shouldn't be promoted.

Comment: Matt, wdym "starting from what point?"?! Just use the mechanism on a dummy project and subtract the relevant part of the resulting version string from the particular date you tested on... :-B

Answer (score 0):

The assembly versioning is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z.aspx

From the quote below, I would say that what you're asking is not possible and your information is incorrect.

> Assembly Version Number Each assembly
>   has a version number as part of its
>   identity. As such, two assemblies that
>   differ by version number are
>   considered by the runtime to be
>   completely different assemblies. This
>   version number is physically
>   represented as a four-part string with
>   the following format:

```
<major version>.<minor version>.<build> number>.<revision>
```

However, at the bottom of the page I linked to, there is information about custom assembly attributes and a link to setting assembly attributes.  You may find something helpful there.
***Edit - added***

I took a look at the link you posted in your answer to my comment, and the only thing I see is this:

> The result of this is a build number
>   set to the number of days since a
>   random, designated start date and the
>   revision based on the number of
>   seconds since midnight.

Based on the fact that it says a "random designated start date" I would say that wha you're asking is probably possible if you can figure out what the random designated start date is, but I doubt it would be worth the effort to find out.

*shameless plug for coding best pactices*

You'd be better served to be using revision control and an automated build process and use the logs from those to determine an asembly's build date.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could calculate the date/time from the auto-generated build number, I wouldn't recommend it.  The build number wasn't meant for that purpose.  It was simply meant to be an auto-generated value you can depend on to continually increase.  No further logic should be assumed by a consuming application.  If you want a fragment of the version number to include a date/time stamp, then you should integrate that logic into your build process / scripts / however else you may choose to do so.

Comment: How do you know I'm building logic on it? Perhaps I'm just looking at a DLL and trying to get a best guess as to when it was built.

Comment: You can have both: eg 170504 is an increasing number and also YYMMDD date. You _don't_ get single step increases, but you may find that's not required.

Answer (score 0):

I use a PostBuild script on my assemblies calling [UpdateVersion](http://code.mattgriffith.net/UpdateVersion/) on the AssemblyInfo.cs
We use the following format for versions |Year|Month|Day|BuildCounter|. 
As the update version is open source, you can modify it to suit.
I've modified it to use the current date  and a counter that is increased each build. 
This way the version number always changes, and I can derive the date from the version number.
Very handy indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but hopefully this will provide another (easy) option for updating version number on build. I used a MSBUILD RegexTransform step to modify the version numbers. Here is a post I frequently go back to when I need to implement this feature.

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/12/07/simple-msbuild-configuration-updating-assemblies-with-a-version-number.aspx

Basically, in your MSBUILD proj file you create a transform on your AssemblyInfo file. Something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <RegexTransform Include="$(SolutionRoot)\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs">
        <Find>(?&lt;major&gt;\d+)\.(?&lt;minor&gt;\d+)\.\d+\.(?&lt;revision&gt;\d+)</Find>
        <ReplaceWith>$(BUILD_NUMBER)</ReplaceWith>
    </RegexTransform>
</ItemGroup>
```

where BUILD_NUMBER is supplied externally:

```
msbuild myBuild.proj /p:Configuration="%config%" /p:build_number="%version%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Use this method */

/// <summary>
/// Gets the Assembly build date in string format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="assemblyVersion"></param>
/// <param name="dateFormat"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string GetAssemblyBuildDate(string assemblyVersion,string dateFormat = "")
{
    DateTime buildDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

    Version currentAssemblyVersion = Version.Parse(assemblyVersion);

    buildDate = buildDate.AddDays(currentAssemblyVersion.Build);

    buildDate = buildDate.AddSeconds(currentAssemblyVersion.Revision * 2);

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateFormat) == false ? buildDate.ToString(dateFormat) : buildDate.ToString();
}
```